# Ngx Select returns null data when data fetched from Remote server Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

When I pass an static array all works fine. But i want my Dynamic Data to be populated there in the select box.

HTML PART IS BELOW

```
  <ngx-select [formControl]="selectedUserId" 
                      [allowClear]="true"
                      [items]="userData"
                      placeholder="No city selected"
                      >
        </ngx-select>
```

TS PART IS BELOW

```
get fromDate() { return this.atAdminName.get('fromDate'); }
  get toDate() { return this.atAdminName.get('toDate'); }
  get selectedUserId() { return this.atAdminName.get('selectedUserId'); }

  constructor(private http: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder, public usr?: UserService, public datepipe?: DatePipe) {

    this.atAdminName = this.fb.group({
      fromDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      toDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
      selectedUserId: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    })

    this.http.getMethod('User/masterpasswordchange').subscribe((data) => {
      this.userData = data;
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    const data: Object = {};
    const userid = this.usr.getUserId();
    this.fdate = this.atAdminName.value.fromDate;
    const fdate = this.datepipe.transform(this.fdate, 'yyyy-dd-MM');
    this.tdate = this.atAdminName.value.toDate;
    const tdate = this.datepipe.transform(this.tdate, 'yyyy-dd-MM');
    const selectedUserId = this.atAdminName.value.selectedUserId;
    Object.assign(data, { userid: userid }, { selectedUserId: selectedUserId }, { fromDate: fdate }, { toDate: tdate });
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: change `(data)` to `(data: any)` in subscribe and see if it works;also log the data and see what returns

Comment: No brother it didn't worked

Comment: set `console.log(data)` and post the console result here

Comment: OK there are many records I am showing you one record - 
{userid: "a", username: "Jignesh", password_set_date: "2018-06-21", password_set_by: "a", password_status: "Active till 2018-06-30", …}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this. See the updated code below.

```
  constructor(private http: HttpService, private fb: FormBuilder, public usr?: UserService, public datepipe?: DatePipe) {
    this.http.getMethod('User/masterpasswordchange').subscribe((data: any) => {
      const items1: Array<any> = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(data).length; i++) {
        items1.push(data[i].userid);
      }
      this.userData = items1;
      console.log(this.userData);
      this.atAdminName = this.fb.group({
        fromDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
        toDate: new FormControl(new Date(), Validators.required),
        selectedUserId: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
      })
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think ngx-select is rendered before the http call completes, so you could put the ngx-select inside a div with *ngIf="userData", so it is going to be rendered after the http call completes.

You could use *ngIf="userData; else #loading" and in loading ng-template show a spinner to indicate it is loading. Search google for Angular if else for many examples on how to do this

Answer (score 0):

according to the ngx-select documentation :

> Items array. Should be an array of objects with id and text
>   properties. As convenience, you may also pass an array of strings, in
>   which case the same string is used for both the ID and the text. Items
>   may be nested by adding a options property to any item, whose value
>   should be another array of items. Items that have children may omit to
>   have an ID.

so you have to provide `id` and `text` for each record in your json result!

look at [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-select-ex) for more details

Comment: Array of string work fine. But dynamic data from http is not getting reflected,

Comment: you mean the dynamic data and array of the strings both have the same format? in your string array you don't have `id` and `text`?

Comment: No see this is the static array which works fine - public items = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona']

Comment: No key value pair is used

Comment: ok it's clear that the array of string works fine, but you get json result from the server and it should have `text` and `id` for mapping to ngx-select, for instance you can change `userid` to `id` and `username` to `text`

Comment: OK let me try once this solution.